# All Vue commands return "Unknown command"

Tags: ubuntu, vue.js

Using Vue 2.9.4 on Ubuntu 18.04, all commands return the error "Unknown command"

```
compustretch@instance-1:~/vuetest$ vue init webpack testapp

  Unknown command init.

  vue-cli · Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/[object Object]: Response code 404 (Not Found)

compustretch@instance-1:~/vuetest$ vue list

  Unknown command list.

  Available official templates:

  ★  browserify - A full-featured Browserify + vueify setup with hot-reload, linting & unit testing.
  ★  browserify-simple - A simple Browserify + vueify setup for quick prototyping.
  ★  pwa - PWA template for vue-cli based on the webpack template
  ★  simple - The simplest possible Vue setup in a single HTML file
  ★  webpack - A full-featured Webpack + vue-loader setup with hot reload, linting, testing & css extraction.
  ★  webpack-simple - A simple Webpack + vue-loader setup for quick prototyping.

compustretch@instance-1:~/vuetest$ vue help init

  Unknown command help.

  vue-[object Object](1) does not exist, try --help

compustretch@instance-1:~/vuetest$ vue --version
2.9.4
compustretch@instance-1:~/vuetest$
```

Hoping someone has an inkling why this is happening, as I've been banging my head on this and there's nothing in search results at all.

Comment: I have the same issue in windows, it seems vue 2.9.4 is a mistake

Comment: Same issue on macOS 10.13.4

Comment: got the same issue on macOS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to uninstall with this command `npm uninstall -g vue-cli`

Then install with v3 with following command `npm install -g @vue/cli` (not sure why they f****d up with current 2.9.4 version)

Also they will require you to install extra stuffs like init, list, etc. after

**UPDATE:**

Forget about `npm install -g @vue/cli` because it's still beta and it gives you a lot of problems when you work with other libraries like nuxt.

I recommend you to try this command `npm install -g vue-cli@2.9.3` it will save you a lot of headcaches.

Comment: vue-cli@2.9.3 works like a charm. on the side note @Ivan you forgot the `-g` flag

Comment: pinning 2.9.3 works fine. wtf happened to 2.9.4‽ And beta seems to be a somewhat generous designation for the current state of v3, imo.

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine with this solution:

1. Uninstall previous version `npm uninstall -g vue-cli`
2. Install vue globally `npm install -g @vue/cli-init`

Comment: props to you for not running into a whole nest of other issues in v3.